# Prove bounded sequences of real numbers

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be bounded sequences of real numbers.

Show that:

$$
\lim \sup(x_n+y_n) \leq \lim \sup x_n+\lim \sup y_n
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Obviously,
$$\sup_{k\geq n}(x_k+y_k)\leq \sup_{k\geq n}x_k+\sup_{k\geq n}y_k.$$

Comment: use the fact that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sup (u_{n})=\inf_{p\in\mathbb{N}}(\sup_{n\ge p}(u_{n}))$$

Comment: @XavierRaymond: or simply that $\limsup_{n\to \infty }u_n=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sup_{k\geq n}u_k$. Even if it's equivalent to your formula, it's less scary for novice people to see limit than infimum and supremum ;-)